# How to install ubuntu 13.04 in ativ book 9 lite

Tags: system-installation

im trying install ubuntu 13.04 but when installation finished cant start ubuntu please help with bios configuration and how to install ubuntu on this ativ book 9 lite.

i try disabling fast boot, disabling secure boot, etc but no result.

Comment: 13.10 came out yesterday, I reccomend you try to install that now it's released.

Comment: I generally wait 2 to 4 weeks before I try new releases.

Comment: Have you tried [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I install windows, update bios then install Ubuntu with out secure boot and with out custom partitions it work then customize partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this machine can boot Ubuntu with secure boot on. Or in Legacy CSM mode(non-EFI) Just boot your install medium in UEFI mode. It won't boot directly after installation, so you need to use a liveUbuntu medium again and [run through boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), So secure boot is correctly set up.

For some unknown reason it refuses to boot regularly, non secured UEFI installations correctly.

Also the samsung-laptop kernel module will be disabled, which makes, for example, some of the hot-keys not to work. It will probably take a long time until that driver is rewritten or Samsung starts to get the reputation that they learn to implement non-brickable firmwares. We'll see, hopefully someone learned a lesson there what happens when you drift away from common standards specifications.